# Query a named text index on a collection in mongo using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm creating a text index on my collection through `mongoose` with a custom name, but I'm not sure how to query that specific text index or if you can even have multiple text indexes on a single collection.

I've specified an index:

```
mongoose.connection.collections['jobs'].ensureIndex({ title: 'text', description: 'text' }, { name: 'customtext' });
```

And I can search it with the general `$text` query:

```
var query = {
  "$text": {
    "$search": "bleep bloop"
  }
}
Model.find(query, function(error, results) {});
```

But is there a way to add multiple different text indexes (for different searches) and query by the custom name?

Comment: You can only use one text index per collection. This also applies to geospatial indexes which are the other special index type.

Comment: @BlakesSeven Ah. Good to know. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A MongoDB collection can have [at most one text index](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/#create-text-index). You cannot define multiple text indexes for a single collection.

Comment: Thank you. I can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

You can have many text indexes with different names, but the name of the index can be used primarily to remove the index.

Example:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex(
   { content: "text"},
   { name: "TextIndex"}
)
db.collection.dropIndex("TextIndex")
```